# Determine if a program is running in debug mode

Tags: ruby, ruby-debug

I use RubyMine to write and debug my Ruby 2.0 code.  It uses ruby-debug-ide for that purpose.  I want to know if a program is running in debug mode.

I know there is the Ruby `$DEBUG` global variable, but as far as I understand ruby-debug-ide didn't change it, because it didn't use the `-d` ruby flag.

If I debug my file using Rubymine the command executed looks like this:

```
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby -e at_exit{sleep(1)};$stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.22/bin/rdebug-ide --disable-int-handler --port 37737 --dispatcher-port 47992 -- /home/user/file.rb
```

I tried to use `ARGV` or `$0`, to determine if the command line contains the string `'rdebug-ide'` but `ARGV` is an empty array and `$0` is just `'/home/user/file.rb'`, how can I get the full command line executed by RubyMine?

Comment: have you tried `ENV['debugger_host'].nil?`

Comment: ENV['debugger_host'].nil? true in both cases

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what I did:

I put the following code in an (rails) action and did a diff on the outputs both in debug and non-debug modes:

```
puts ENV.to_hash.to_yaml
```

I noticed that one of the differences is in `ENV['RUBYLIB']` (there's also `IDE_PROCESS_DISPATCHER`, `DEBUGGER_STORED_RUBYLIB`, `RUBYOPT`, `and DEBUGGER_HOST`)

So here's how you'd  check:

```
if ENV['RUBYLIB'] =~ /ruby-debug-ide/
  puts 'in debug mode'
else
  puts 'not in debug mode'
end
```

Comment: Works, at least in RubyMine + rvm. Thanks!

Comment: @PerLundberg check my method and do your own diff to figure out what works for you environment

Comment: @Abdo Checked now. None of RUBYLIB or the other env variables mentioned have any unusual values when being run through the VSCode debugger.

Comment: @PerLundberg I don't use VSCode but I suggest changing the debugging command (there should be somewhere where you can add variables to it). Now that I'm thinking about this question/answer, I'm not sure that was useful. Have you tried `gem pry-rails` ?

Comment: As @PerLundberg mentioned, on VSCode running `puts ENV.to_hash.to_yaml` with (F5) or without (Ctrl+F5) debugger returns the same output.

Answer (score 1):

You need the global variable `$LOAD_PATH`.

```
a = $LOAD_PATH
a.each do |current_path|
    puts 'Debug mode' if current_path.include?('rb/gems')
end
```

`$LOAD_PATH` has this line `"/home/username/RubyMine-6.0.2/rb/gems"` if I use debug mode.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please edit your answer to include an example showing how to use the variable `$LOAD_PATH` to achieve what OP wants?

Comment: Sorry for mislead. For me this variant work only if clean .rb file. But if I use it in my project - both debug and run $LOAD_PATH contains 'ruby-debug', don't know why